# How to use a output of a Databricks activity in future activity inside ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have a Databricks activity in ADF and I pass the output with the below code:

```
 dbutils.notebook.exit(message_json)
```

Now, I want to use this output for the next Databrick activity.

[image]

As my search, I think add the last output into base parameters in the second activity. Am I right?

[image]

and other questions, How can I use this output inside the Databrick notebook?

Edited: The output is a JSON as the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: What do you exactly mean by output here?

Comment: @AliHasan I added at end of the question. The output is JSON, as in the above screenshot. I want to load this JSON in the filter notebook.

Comment: You can do this in databricks, save file in temp table if possible or in dbfs and then again read file in next databricks notebook. As you also have intentions to use this in databricks notebook.

Comment: @AliHasan I'm looking for a solution using the output of the last activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-notebook#passing-parameters-between-notebooks-and-data-factory), you can consume the output of Databrick Notebook activity in data factory by using expression such as `@{activity('databricks notebook activity name').output.runOutput}`.

If you are passing JSON object you can retrieve values by appending property names.

Example: `@{activity('databricks notebook activity name').output.runOutput.PropertyName}`.

I reproduced the issue and it's working fine.

**Below is the sample notebook.**

```
import json
dates = ['2017-12-11', '2017-12-10', '2017-12-09', '2017-12-08', '2017-12-07']
return_json = json.dumps(dates)
dbutils.notebook.exit(return_json)
```

This is how the Notebook2 Activity Seeting looks like:
[image]

Pipeline ran successfully.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response and looks great. Other than my question, how can I consume this output to notebook2? Could you share the sample code? for example in notebook2 if the date == '2017-12-10' print yes.

Comment: you can use the ```If Condition``` activity in ADF and based on True/False can trigger another activity for further process in the pipeline. refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity

Comment: Thanks, I mean use notebook1's output in the body of notebook2. `If Condition` is a sample operation. I try to clarify my request.

Comment: I mean how to use `return_json` in the body of notebook2?

Comment: unable to understand the exact requirement. do you want to write the ```return_json``` in notebook2? or want to iterate json objects? or anything else?

Comment: Thanks I found a solution in your response.